# Get value from attribute equals to

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse an xml file using Python which has the following line

```
<Stat Type="total_pass">37</Stat>
```

I would like to get the 37 value giving a certain attribute - in this case it would be `total_pass`.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: The problem is that I can't get the '37' when the attribute is equal to 'total_pass'. The tag is Stat, the attribute is 'Type' and I want to know the value when the Type is equal to 'total_pass', for example.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '<r><Stat Type="total_pass">37</Stat><Stat Type="other">33</Stat></r>'

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
stat_with_total_pass = root.find(".//Stat[@Type='total_pass']")
print(stat_with_total_pass.text)
```

output

```
37
```